# Will I pay taxes twice if I move from eTrade to another platform?

Tags: taxes, stocks, robinhood

I have vested shares at the company I work at. Somewhere around $40k worth, in an eTrade account. I've paid due taxes through share withholding, but have not sold yet because I believe in the company and its long term future.

I have used robinhood over the last couple years for all other stock transactions, and quite like it. So I thought, maybe I would sell all of the shares from eTrade, and use those funds to purchase my company stock through another platform, where I won't have to pay commissions.

Would I end up paying taxes again on the other platform? Or is there another reason this is not a good idea?

Note: My company policy does not disallow holding shares outside of eTrade, as long as transactions are performed during certain open windows.

Comment: Why on earth would you move money to robinhood when other more established and brokers that offer more services also offer $0 commissions?

Comment: Maybe your account has $0 commissions, but mine doesn't. I made a trade today and paid $16.99 in commission, plus $0.24 SEC

Comment: Schwab is $0.  TD is $0.  Fidelity is $0.  It baffles me why anyone would use robinhood.

Comment: because it's easy and intuitive, and you don't have to wait weeks for money to transfer. Either way, I'm not married to robinhood. I'll modify the question to include other choices

Comment: Fidelity is intuitive, IMO, and money transfers only take a few working days.

Comment: There's no reason to liquidate your positions to change brokerages, any good brokerage will support asset transfers.

Comment: @HartCO: There may be a fee for asset transfer which is likely far more than the commission on a single position.

Comment: @Felipe: Was that a broker-assisted trade?  E-Trade commissions on trades made online have been under $10 for a long time, even before the recent drop to $0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Never sell stocks then buy.  You *transfer shares*

Any competent trading platform should allow you to transfer stock shares to another platform *directly*.  That way a sell and buy does not occur, you do not pay capital gains, and any question of "wash sales" never arises.

You can tell eTrade to move your shares, say, to a Fidelity account. (I've done this).

You can tell Fidelity to move your shares to a Charitable Donor Advised Fund account, *as shares, not selling them*.  This has an interesting effect on your charitable tax deduction.   If you sold the shares, *then* donated, you would pay 10-15% capital gains tax on the proceeds.  However if you transfer the shares directly, *the charity* pays the capital gains tax. They get a special rate: 0%.

Thus, moving shares *as shares* is always the better thing to do.

### If you insist on selling-buying, that is trouble.

You need to pay capital gains on the sale. The re-buy gives you a new cost basis and purchase date.  Several big problems with that.

- If you are forced to sell within 1 year, that (second) sale is taxed as a **short-term capital gain** at your salary tax rate (22-32%) not the long-term capital gains tax rate (10-15%) you'd be entitled to if you transferred it.
- If the stock then goes down, you may not be able to recover the capital losses (even though you paid the capital gains).  You are limited in how much capital loss you can deduct each year ($3000 + you can cancel any capital gains).  You can carry the losses forward to future years, to use against future capital gains (plus your annual $3000).
- You can lose gains if the stock jumps upward during the time between your sale and repurchase.
- If your tax bracket falls between the move-it sale and the actually-wanted-to-sell-it sale, you wasted money paying capital gains at the higher rate.
- Under certain edge conditions, the sell-buy can raise tax issues with a "wash sale". That is where the sell-buy gives you a tax advantage the IRS considers improper.

Comment: Although you can only use $3k per year, there is no time limit (3 years or otherwise) on carryforward of net capital loss for individuals. (For _investment companies_ like mutual funds there are time limits and Congress keeps tweaking them so I've given up trying to keep track.) Otherwise concur.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Oh, there is for charitable contributions! You can only roll those forward 3 years (FIFO) but obviously each year you can take 20/30/50% of AGI depending on the contrib, so you're likely to make it.

Answer (score 3):

You might pay taxes "twice" if you have *gains* after selling both times. You're already paid the income taxes for the vested shares, but if the stocks have gained value since you were vested then you'll pay capital gains tax on the gain. If they then rise *again* on another platform then you'll pay taxes on *that* gain.

So you're not paying taxes on the same thing twice - you're paying taxes on two independent gains.

Of course, if you sell either time for a *loss* then that loss could be used to offset any other taxable investment gains.

That said, I would not necessarily be in a hurry to move away from your current broker *just to save in transaction costs*.  e*Trade also offers no commission right now, but even if they had a commission, whether you sell now, or a year from now (to turn your gains from short-term to long-term and reduce your taxes) you're going to pay commission either way.

In other words, your plan is essentially to pay a commission now to avoid paying the *same* commission in the future. If you want to use a different platform, that's fine, but I don't see transaction costs as a valid reason to do so.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the income tax vs gains tax in this situation. It was a source of confusion for me